# Validating stored procedures in .NET project against database project in solution

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-data-tools

I have a very large data access layer that references close to a few thousand stored procedures across it. I also have a very large SSDT project in the same solution.

Are there any tools out there that can validate the procedures referenced in my SQL Command objects / other ADO.NET commands actually exist in the SSDT project as stored procedures?

It would be nice to perform a check like this during testing or a build to validate someone didn't change a name wrong or refactor something and forget to rename the procedure references also

I'm working in VS 2019 / VS 2022 Preview and Rider right now so any solutions in one of those would be great.

Comment: wouldn't the SSDT project just fail if there is broken reference?

Comment: How would SSDT link to a SQL Command object that references a stored procedure in a .NET C# project to know that a procedure maps to a procedure in the SSDT project? As far as I know SSDT only checks decencies and references within itself and other referenced databases

Comment: yes, your .NET project is separate world for SSDT. You can write the script that will parse out the object list from .NET then compare it with what you have in your `.sqlproj` file. It can be done automatically on each build via build contributors

Comment: yes, obviously, but I was just asking if there are any existing solutions out there to save me some time